# command line argument issue

Tags: c#, console, console-application, system.io.file

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          origination = args[1];
          desti = args[3];
          Console.ReadLine();
          string[] args1 = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
                    origination = args1[1];
                    desti = args1[3];
}
```

I am having issue first time i am getting right value of command argument
but when i am applying new values on command prompt args it not updating new value its always returning old value
i need help how to get latest value when user add new command args.

Comment: What do you mean by 'adding' new command args? The command arguments are only passed when the command is invoked; they can't be changed later

Comment: so what is other option if i am applying default args by setting project ->properties -> debug I am getting default result  but now i want to add changes or over write that default args to get new result how to overwrite?

Comment: Also when i running in debug mode its giving me result based on default args value but when i run  search.exe then press enter nothing comming on command prompt

Answer (score 0):

That is because `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` takes the arguments passed to the process at the moment it was invoked. You're actually re-reading them, and the text you're asked to input simply goes nowhere. What you need is

```
string newArg = Console.ReadLine();
string[] newArgs = Regex.Split(newArg, " ");
```

where `Regex` is a `System.Text.RegularExpressions` namespace method.

Comment: why using the Regex class at all? why not just use the String.split method? string[] splitted = newArg.split(' ');